# Mautic form getting stuck on "Please Wait"

Tags: forms, amazon-web-services, bitnami, mautic

I have embedded a muatic form in a wordpress site (different domain) and when I click on Download in the form it gave the following error:

```
Refused to display 'https://mymauticinstance.com/form/submit?formId=1' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'
```

So I modified the the configuration in httpd.conf to be:

"allow-from https://www.mywordpresssite.com/"

Which gave the error:

```
Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered : 'ALLOWFROM is not a recognized directive
```

So I changed it to ALLOWALL.

But now after I click the Download Button it's stuck on "Please Wait". When I inspect the network responses in Chrome I see that the error is:

```
Request URL: https://mymauticinstance.com/media/js/mautic-form.js
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently (from disk cache)
Remote Address: 1.2.3.4:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

I also tried to "Rebuild Cache" from within the Mautic Forms page.

Note: I'm using Chrome, Mautic 2.15.1 hosted on an AWS Bitnami instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the Site URL in the Mautic config settings page to include the "www" to the site url.

Answer (score 0):

with the given description I am not very sure but here is what you can check first:

1. There is some kind of internal redirect, are you using reverse proxy ? if so is there any possibility it might be forwarding request by strapping headers ?
2. Check if you are getting any errors in mautic log.

unfortunately the information isn't enough, to guess or think of solution, as the problem isn't yet very clear.

Answer (score 0):

> I have embedded a Mautic form in a WordPress site (different domain) ...
>   Note: I'm using Chrome, Mautic 2.15.1 hosted on an AWS Bitnami instance...

Could you please provide more information about your setup? It's not very clear to me how you configured Mautic and WordPress... Is it a WordPress instance or a Mautic instance?

Comment: I have 2 separate instances on 2 different domains. Mautic on one box and WordPress on the other. WordPress has a reference to the Mautic form.